# asp.net mvc3 form authentication, is it possible to set multi AuthCookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider

after user sign in. I save their username into the cookie.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
```

User has roles, "member", "staff", "manager"

for those page that only manager are allowed to enter.  What I did right now is to query the DB using  their username.

GetRoles(username)

That generates alot overhead, every time they visit a role protected page, I need to check the DB.

I am wondering if I can make SetAutheCookie to set a few values, not just the username.

What I did right now to combine username, roles in one string.

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName + "|" + role.tostring(), createPersistentCookie);

this definitely not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most-upvoted answer to this SO question provides an example of storing and retrieving roles in a forms authentication cookie: [Store/assign roles of authenticated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822548/mvc-how-to-store-assign-roles-of-authenticated-users)