# In ASP.NET Core 3 (3.0) SPA (Angular) how to properly check for user roles?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

I've been looking around how to use roles in SPA, and the basic project that Visual Studio (2019) creates is quite fine, however `[Authorize(Roles="")]` does not work properly, so I can use Authorize attribute to check if user is actually logged in but not the role.

My approach now in controllers is to get the user and use `IsInRole()`, but this seems like a big overhead since I should have his token already which should include the role.

```
ClaimsPrincipal currentUser = this.User;
var currentUserId = currentUser.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
User user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(currentUserId);

if (await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "Admin"))
...
```

Comment: UPDATE:

So it turns out the proper authentication scheme for me was `Identity.Application`. 

Using it this way `[Authorize(Roles="...", AuthenticationSchemes ="Identity.Application")]` works.

Answer (score 0):

You should stick to the original `[Authorize(Roles="")]` attribute.

As stated here:[Store/assign roles of authenticated users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822548/store-assign-roles-of-authenticated-users)

> Roles are added to the IPrincipal of the HttpContext. You can create a GenericPrincipal, parse the list of roles in the constructor and set it as HttpContext.User. The GenericPrincipal will then be accessible through User.IsInRole("role") or the [Authorize(Roles="role")] attribute

Depending on your authentication scheme, you need to create a GenericPrincipal and add the roles there for all requests so that they can be accessed.

Example for FormsAuthentication is in the mentioned answer.